# Firebase Authentication web not signing in

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I'm new to flutter web and I was working on a project that works fine on android

The problem is when I deploy to firebase hosting and click the google sign in button.
The pop up shows and I am able to sign in but when it pops out my app doesn't receive the FirebaseAuth.User Object and it stays null even when I evalute firebase.auth().currentUser expression in the console in browser

**My index.html file:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<my client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="ChurchData">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>App</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>

  <!-- Load the Firebase SDKs before loading this file -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screeenshot from Chrome**
[image: console logs from Chrome]

**Screenshot from Firefox**
[image: console logs from Firefox]

Comment: I think you should try focusing the question. Is the signin working when running in debug mode for example? Have you tried the example project of FirebaseAuth for web? If so did that work?

Comment: @Alex.F thanks so much. I looked at the example and tried the natvie javascript code and it worked. May be the problem is with the flutter google sign in plugin.